# Geocoder and rails - wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I read all posts but don't find solution. I make a .near request with geocoder, and It work for one controller but doesn't work for another one with this error : Wrong number of arguments (3 for 1).

Here is the two same lines :

This one doesn't work in my school_controller.rb

```
@schools_premium = School.where(:subscription.exists => true)

@schools_aside = @schools_premium.near([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]], radius, units: :km).limit(3)
```

I try too with : @school.coordinates.reverse instead of params[:latitude] ..

But this one does (in home_controller.rb) :

```
@schools = School.near([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]], radius, units: :km).limit(30)
```

I have the `geocoded_by` and `reverse_geocoder` on my School model.

Does someone have the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by this way also:

```
@schools = School.near([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]], radius, units: :km).limit(30)
@schools_aside =  @schools.premium_school
```

School.rb (model)

```
scope :premium_school, -> {where("subscription = ?", true)}
```

Comment: I edited my answer please have a look and let me know?

Comment: I have this error : "Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)" for .where()

Comment: I fix it by using : `scope :premium_school, -> {where(:subscription.exists => true)}` but now I have this error `Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 0.007848061528802385 (17287)`

Comment: What database you are using? https://forums.meteor.com/t/unable-to-get-near-working/7063/2

Comment: I using mongodb, but it work now with your second solution, I'm going to put your answer as validated! thank you !